# Docker desktop with Windows built-in OpenSSH client: All pipe instances are busy

Tags: windows, docker, named-pipes, openssh, ssh-agent

My docker image should be able to access private git repository on github via ssh. For that I am trying to make host's ssh client accessible to the builder. The image should not store secrets and should work on any host whatever that host may be.

On my windows machine I do the following (inside the folder containing my Dockerfile):

```
SET SSH_AUTH_SOCK=\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent
SET DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
docker build --ssh default .
```

And I get:

```
could not parse ssh: [default]: failed to open \\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent: open \\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent: All pipe instances are busy.
```

The outcome doesn't depend on the contents of the Dockerfile: same happens with any Dockerfile, such as this:

```
FROM alpine:latest
```

---

Versions info:

**OpenSSH** (by running `ssh -V`):

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
```

(originally it was `8.1`; the error was already present)

**docker** (by running `docker version`):

```
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.20
 Version:           20.10.10
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.9
 Git commit:        b485636
 Built:             Mon Oct 25 07:47:53 2021
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.10
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.9
  Git commit:       e2f740d
  Built:            Mon Oct 25 07:41:30 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.11
  GitCommit:        5b46e404f6b9f661a205e28d59c982d3634148f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.2
  GitCommit:        v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Other info:

`\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent` is present within the output of
`[System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("\\.\\pipe\\")` (ran in powershell)

ssh-agent StartupType is set to Automatic and `GET-SERVICE ssh-agent` (ran in powershell) says the service is Running